# Test if the HTML attribute is present and get the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I am trying to test if the HTML attribute is present and get the value using has Attribute("tabindex") property. But I am getting the below error:

> Unable to get property 'hasAttribute' of undefined or null reference

I am using jGrid and jQuery. If the attribute is present I am trying to get the value of that particular td.

Please refer to the code below:

```
<tr class="jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-widget-content  myAltRowClassEven ui-state-highlight" tabindex="0" id="2" role="row" aria-selected="true">
    <td aria-describedby="jqGrid11_cname" title=" TESTTHIS" class="zeroBorderRight" style="text-align: left; height: 20px;" role="gridcell">
        TESTTHIS
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How are you selecting the html element? `Unable to get xxx of undefined` leads me to believe there may be an issue with your reference to the element

Comment: Would you mind to post the code of your test? It would be easier to tell you what is the error if we could see the code.

Comment: You included "jqgrid" as the tag of your question. It would be helpful if you formulate the problem more clear: where (in which callback) you need to test the existence of some attribute. Including of JavaScript code could clear many things.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#item").attr("tabindex")
```

Comment: This worked out. Thanks a lot for all for your solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tag it has the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to filterout element with `tabindex` attribute.

```
var text = $('td[tabindex]').text();
//--------------^^^^^^^^^^--------------------
```

Comment: Hi @Pranav . Thanks a lot for your suggestion. But the problem is the table is in a loop and has lot of td with tabindex. Sorry I forgot to mention that it is in the loop.

Comment: @user3213490 `[tabindex]` will help to filter out .... for eg : `$('.yourclass[tabindex]')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values of the tabindex attribute you can do:

```js
$(function () {
  $('table tbody tr[tabindex]').each(function (i, e) {
    var tabindex = e.getAttribute('tabindex');
    console.log('tabindex=' + tabindex + ' Row text: ' + e.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-widget-content  myAltRowClassEven ui-state-highlight" id="1" role="row"
        aria-selected="true">
        <td aria-describedby="jqGrid11_cname" title=" TESTTHIS" class="zeroBorderRight"
            style="text-align: left; height: 20px;" role="gridcell"> TESTTHIS
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-widget-content  myAltRowClassEven ui-state-highlight" tabindex="0" id="2" role="row"
        aria-selected="true">
        <td aria-describedby="jqGrid11_cname" title=" TESTTHIS" class="zeroBorderRight"
            style="text-align: left; height: 20px;" role="gridcell"> TESTTHIS
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-widget-content  myAltRowClassEven ui-state-highlight" tabindex="2" id="3" role="row"
        aria-selected="true">
        <td aria-describedby="jqGrid11_cname" title=" TESTTHIS" class="zeroBorderRight"
            style="text-align: left; height: 20px;" role="gridcell"> TESTTHIS
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution without jquery, es6

```
var hasAttr = [...document.getElementById('#blah').attributes]
  .map(a => a.name)
  .indexOf(ATTRIBUTE) > -1;
```